# Is it ever useful to take the identity map as a covering map to define a covering space?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I don't see why not, but can the identity map be used as a covering map to define a covering space? $$p : X \longrightarrow X,\ p= \text{identity of } X$$

If so, what is an example of this use? Is it ever useful?

I can't find any text where we have this, so I'm wondering if there's something in the definitions involving covering spaces that prevents this or if it's just not very helpful.

Comment: Yes it can, but it's not super useful

Comment: @Max I see. Do we call it the "trivial covering'' or that terminology is reserved for something else?

Comment: There is a spectral sequence for a fibration, that upon taking the fibration to be the identity (fibrations are generalizations of covering spaces) recovers the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a somewhat useful statement by saying 'A space $X$ is simply connected if and only if the identity map is the universal covering map.'

This is sort of the reverse of the definition of the universal cover. A covering space $Y \rightarrow X$ is called the universal cover of $X$ if $Y$ is simply connected.

Comment: Thanks. A proof doesn't sound too hard, but would you be okay with providing a short one, so that I can be sure I understand this, please?

Comment: Also, by "..the identity map is the universal cover." Do you mean the identity map is the *covering map* of the universal cover of $X$?

Comment: It is often useful to include "trivial " cases. Look at the history of zero ! .